# Is disposing the SqlTransaction required?

Tags: c#, .net, dispose

I have this repeating  pattern in code:

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
  conn.Open();
  using (SqlTransaction trans = conn.BeginTransaction())
  {
  ...
  }
}
```

I know it doesn't hurt to use `using` for `IDisposable`, but for my reasons (might be off topic and too long to explain here), I prefer not to have the `using` for the `SqlTransaction`. I also looked at the demo from MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqltransaction(v=vs.110).aspx
Which *does not* uses `using` or disposes the `SqlTransaction`.

Note that the `SqlConnection` have `using` which is fine.

Now my question, is disposing the `SqlTransaction` is *required*? will be `SqlConnection` dispose the `SqlTransaction` resources also? if yes, how can I verify that?